# Cannot change postgresql 9.6 max_connections Ubuntu 16

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgis, postgresql-9.6, tilemill

I'm running postgresql 9.6 with postgis on Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm running into a bizarre problem while running the tilemill app which is giving "too many clients already" error.  So I go inside /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf and I set

```
max_connections = 200;
```

and perform a restart without error.

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main restart
```

I check psql and run the following:

[image: psql_queriies]

Meanwhile, if I were to go back inside /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf and increase the following to a number greater than max_connections (5),

[image]

I cannot restart the server because:

> ip-172-31-48-27 postgresq;@9.6-main[16228]: postgres: superuser_reserved_connections must be less than max connections

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX4p4.png)

Comment: Here is question an answer how to find the actual source of the parameter value: [Finding what the source of a specific PostgreSQL configuration setting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/179759/88191)

Comment: Great tip. It looks as if some of these configurations were being overridden by the postgis install and an alternate config file. I was able to track it down with `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE sourcefile = '/data/postgis/9.6/main/postgresql.auto.conf'`.

Comment: So if the source of the `max_connections` parameter is `postgresql.auto.conf` then you have two ways: remove it from there by hands or by `alter system reset max_connections;` [command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) or edit it at the `system` level in the same way.

Comment: Indeed, that's how I did it.  Thank you.